# Filter pandas dataframe based on opposite condition whether True/False in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the duplicates rows in a pandas dataframe from the below dataframe on the column "msgid" and keep the values satisfying below conditions:

Start by evaluating "tr_flag":

1. if mix of True and False, then keep True
2. if all False , then keep min(evid)
3. if more than one true then keep max(evid).

I tried the approach of using sql : by using Case statement and partition by msgid. But not able to get all three scenarios able to get first and second only. Is sql ok or any other better approach?

dataset:

```
         Date plid  evid msgid tr_type  tr_flag
0  08-11-2021  pl1   111  msg1     new    False
1  08-11-2021  pl1   222  msg1     new    False
2  08-11-2021  pl1   333  msg1     new    False
3  08-11-2021  pl1   444  msg2     new    False
4  08-11-2021  pl1   555  msg2     new     True
5  08-11-2021  pl1   666  msg2     new    False
6  08-11-2021  pl1   777  msg3     new     True
7  08-11-2021  pl1   888  msg3     new     True
8  08-11-2021  pl1   999  msg3     new     True
```

Comment: can you provide a text/code sample of the dataframe to work with?

Comment: Date plid evid msgid tr_type tr_flag
08-11-2021 pl1 111 msg1 new FALSE
08-11-2021 pl1 222 msg1 new FALSE
08-11-2021 pl1 333 msg1 new FALSE
08-11-2021 pl1 444 msg2 new FALSE
08-11-2021 pl1 555 msg2 new TRUE
08-11-2021 pl1 666 msg2 new FALSE
08-11-2021 pl1 777 msg3 new TRUE
08-11-2021 pl1 888 msg3 new TRUE
08-11-2021 pl1 999 msg3 new TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a custom sorting key (here negative 'tr_flag' for True, positive for False), sort on the key, `groupby` 'msgid` and keep first row:

```
(df.assign(key=df['tr_flag'].eq(False).mul(2).sub(1).mul(df['evid']))
   .sort_values(by='key')
   .groupby('msgid').first()
   .drop('key', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
             Date plid  evid tr_type  tr_flag
msgid                                        
msg1   08-11-2021  pl1   111     new    False
msg2   08-11-2021  pl1   555     new     True
msg3   08-11-2021  pl1   999     new     True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mozway. Do you see any issues in extending this solution to a spark dataframe?. This piece of work needs to be incorporated in a glue job (pyspark) as a part of processing the source data and getting the required data..

Comment: I can't tell you as I am not using pyspark, you should probably open a new question specifically for the pyspark aspect.